# Highlighten specific x-axis values

Tags: plot, matlab, matlab2tikz

I need some help to plot a small figure for my thesis. I know that the question is towards Matlab, but I export the figure as a tikzpicture and genuinely think that you guys deliver the better solution.

I think the question is quite simple but however I have not found a solution yet...
What I want to do is to plot my figure with its x-axis that ranges from 0 to 5 in steps of 0.5. Now I want to add 2 specific values (say 1.1 and 3.387) to the x-axis and label them as f_1 and f_2. I tried using xtick but it did not work.

[image]

The tikz code as exported from Matlab:

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=6.028in,
height=4.754in,
at={(1.011in,0.642in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=5,
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={Frequency [Hz]},
ymin=0,
ymax=40,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={$\text{Acceleration [m/s}^\text{2}\text{]}$},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={Dynamic Operating Space},
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot [color=red, dashed]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1.15749049521378    0\\
1.15749049521378    40\\
};
\addlegendentry{data1}

\addplot [color=red, dashed]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
3.48151438013521    0\\
3.48151438013521    40\\
};
\addlegendentry{data2}

\addplot [color=black, line width=2.0pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0\\
1.15749049521378    11.6363636363636\\
};
\addlegendentry{data3}

\addplot [color=black, line width=2.0pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1.15749049521378    11.6363636363636\\
3.48151438013521    35\\
};
\addlegendentry{data4}

\addplot [color=black, line width=2.0pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
3.48151438013521    35\\
5   35\\
};
\addlegendentry{data5}

\node[right, align=left, rotate=45]
at (axis cs:0.3,5.5) {$\text{x}_{\text{max}}\text{ = 0.22m}$};
\node[right, align=left, rotate=45]
at (axis cs:2,22.5) {$\text{v}_{\text{max}}\text{ = 1.6m/s}$};
\node[right, align=left]
at (axis cs:4,36.5) {$\text{a}_{\text{max}}\text{ = 35m/s}^\text{2}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

If the x-axis would now display the full range in addition to above f_1 and f_2 I'd be very happy.

Any clue ? 
Additionally, is there any way to grey out the area under the curves ?

Thank you !

Comment: Could you post the `tikz` code that is generated for this figure, as part of a small compilable document? Without that it is not really possible to tell you how you can get the output that you want.

Comment: @Marijn just added my code :)

Comment: You can achieve this with `extra x ticks={1.1,3.387},
extra x tick labels={$f_1$,$f_2$}`. Do you want to keep the current ticks?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thank you ! Got it ;)